# PHP on Server downloads empty images

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, curl

I've got a php function that downloads youtube thumbnails to the server, and it works fine on my local version, however as soon as it gets uploaded to the server all of the .jpg files that it downloads are empty.

```
function download_thumbnail() {

  preg_match('/src="(.+?)"/', get_field('youtube_link'), $matches); //Pull the URL of the video out of the iframe generated by ACF
  preg_match("/embed\/(.+)\?/", $matches[1], $vid_id); //Pull the ID of the video from the URL

  $download_url = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/".$vid_id[1]."/maxresdefault.jpg"; //Use the standard youtube link to get the max res thumbnail

  $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
  $path = $uploads['path']."/"; //Get the upload path

  $filename = $vid_id[1].'.jpg'; //Set the filename as the ID of the video

  $save_as = $path.$filename; //Full path of the created file

  if(!file_exists($save_as)) { //Check if file exists
   $ch = curl_init($download_url); //Initialize the PHP cURL to the youtube page

   $fp = fopen($save_as, 'wb'); //Start the path link

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); //Download the image to the path link
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   fclose($fp);

   $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $save_as ), null ); //Check the file type

   $attachment = array( //Create neccessary wordpress data to the image
   'guid'           => $uploads['url'] . '/' . basename( $save_as ),
   'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
   'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $save_as ) ),
   'post_content'   => '',
   'post_status'    => 'inherit'
   );

   $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $save_as, get_the_ID() ); //Add neccessary wordpress data to the image
   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' ); //Make sure that the image gets registered as an image


   $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $save_as ); //Generate more meta data
   wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data ); //Attatch the meta data

   set_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), $attach_id ); //Set image as the featured image
  }
  }
```

Any help / insight is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did you tried to access youtube through the server ?

Comment: Yes, the function takes an iframe, uses regex to get the ID of the video and then downloads the image from https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insertvidIDhere>/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: `curl_exec` is probably returning `false`. You're not testing the return value, and you're not calling `curl_errno`, so you don't know what the error is. Best to start there. Possibly you need `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: Thanks Chris, that worked perfectly